react-map-gl Popup above polygon - Invalid LngLat object: (NaN, NaN)
I have an interactive Mapbox map using react-map-gl. It is displaying a GEOJSON with polygons and I would like to show a popup on hover at the center of the polygon. Each feature has a "properties" of "center" which contains the center coordinates of the polygon.
This is a sample of the GEOJSON:

{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -73.971451,
                            40.757749
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.970993,
                            40.758373
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.972613,
                            40.759059
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.973068,
                            40.758432
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "center": [
                    -73.97203144204987,
                    40.75840349835226
                ]
            }
        },

This is a sample of what my code looks like:
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Map, { Source, Layer, Popup } from 'react-map-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

import SAMPLE_DATA from '../assets/sample.geojson';

// ...

const BgMap = ({ showLayer }) => {
    const [hoverPopupInfo, setHoverPopupInfo] = useState(null);

    const handleMouseEnter = useCallback((event) => {
        const { features } = event;
        if (features.length > 0) {
            const feature = features[0];
            const center = feature.properties.center;
            setHoverPopupInfo({ center });
        }
    });

    return (
        <div className="map-container">
            <Map
                // ...
                interactiveLayerIds={['aggregated-layer']}
                onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
            >
                <Source id="aggregated-data" type="geojson" data={AGGREGATED_DATA}>
                    <Layer
                        id="aggregated-layer"
                        type="fill"
                        paint={{
                            'fill-color': '#fff',
                        }}
                    />
                </Source>
                {hoverPopupInfo && (
                    <Popup
                        latitude={hoverPopupInfo.center[1]}
                        longitude={hoverPopupInfo.center[0]}
                        closeButton={false}
                        anchor="bottom"
                    >
                        <div>This is a popup</div>
                    </Popup>
                )}

            </Map>
        </div>
    );
};

But I get an error like this:
Invalid LngLat object: (NaN, NaN)

